# Selection deselection event eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I change a selection in eclipse treeviewer, it appears to have two selection events, one for the deselected item and the other for selected item, in that order.
This is not at all desirable at some times, especially if it involves making server calls. Is there anyway to avoid the first selection event i.e. event from deselection?